# How to export jdeveloper sequence diagram into any image format?

Tags: jdeveloper, sequence-diagram

Good evening, i made a sequence diagram on jdeveloper and i want to export it into any image format instead of the .sequence extension, does any one know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also generate documentation for the project and get the diagram in HTML.
From the build menu.

Answer (score 1):

In JDeveloper 11.1.2.4
Right click on the diagram and select publish diagram
or Select Diagram in the menu and then Publish Diagram.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to assist you without knowing what version of JDeveloper you're using.  Generally speaking you right click on diagrams in JDeveloper and select the Publish Diagram option, where upon the resulting dialog gives you a number of file formats to save the diagrams as.